# How do I copy a subset of polylines from existing vtkPolyData?

Tags: c++, vtk

I have a set of polylines: oldData.
I wish to display only some of these polylines based on a "filter": showLine:

```
void myFunction(vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> oldData, 
                std::vector<boolean> showLine) {
    // "Filtered" polylines: 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> newData = vtkPolyData::New();

    // .. ???

    displayFunction(newData);
 }
```

**How do I copy the polylines where showLine[i] == true into newData?**

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Answer (score 3):

First, this is not valid:

vtkSmartPointer newData = vtkPolyData::New();

You should either do

vtkSmartPointer newData = vtkSmartPointer::New();

or

vtkPolyData* newData = vtkPolyData::New();

For your real question, you'd need to get the lines out of the oldData:

vtkLine* line = oldData->GetCell(i); // the syntax might be hairier than this...

and then put it into the new data:

newData->InsertNextCell(line);  // again, the syntax might be a bit hairier than this...